# How to accomodate empty data set in ListPlot, ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, data, missing

The simple case often arises where multiple data sets are generated, and one or more is empty. `ListPlot` and related functions fail to plot such multidata sets. The following example throws an error and returns unevaluated.

```
setA = {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {7, 5}};
setB = {};
ListPlot[{setA, setB}]

(* During evaluation of In[1]:= ListPlot::lpn: {{{1.000000000000000,2.000000000000000},{3.000000000000000,6.000000000000000},{7.000000000000000,5.000000000000000}},{}} is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. *)
```

Same with e.g. `ListLinePlot[<|"A" -> setA, "B" -> setB|>]`.

Obviously, I'd like to have all datasets annotated, and labels appearing in legends even for empty data.
What is the simplest way to enforce the plotter to display correctly?

(*Mathematica* 13.3 under Windows 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setA = {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {7, 5}};
setB = {};

ListPlot[{setA, setB} /. {} :> {Missing[]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosty, do you have any idea why this replacement is not handled automatically? What was the intention behind disallowing empty datasets?

Comment: It doesn't work on v12.2; perhaps it is a recently introduced feature.

Comment: @syed Perhaps it is related to `PlotHighlighting`?

Comment: No idea, and  it's interesting to note that you have to put curly brackets around `Missing[]`, and that `{{}}` doesn't function, but {Null} does. I'm on V 13.3.0